# MySQL: Re-using user-defined variables in the same SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, variables, select, user-defined

I did a search in stackoverflow but didn't quite find an exact answer to my question, so please help me if you can.

I 'want' to build a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT
  @tax1 := (complicated calculation formula),
  @owe := (another complicated calculation formula),
  IF(@owe=0, 0,@tax1/@owe)
FROM ...
```

However, in MySQL's documentation regarding [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html), it advises against it saying:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server. In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

My goal is to avoid copying-and-pasting those very complicated formulas because it hinders readability and if the formula every changes, I need to ensure that it is changed in all places - BUT I do know by doing so, it'll work just fine.

Additionally, I know that ALIAS *doesn't* work because aliases only work in GROUP BY, HAVING and ORDER clauses.

I read in some other posts to do a sub-query first to calculate @tax1 and @owe first, then use another query to combine the results.  BUT I'm thinking that the performance may be less efficient than just simply copying-and-pasting those formulas in-place.

Does anyone have any suggestion what they would do?  Or am I stuck with choosing between readability and performance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the only way to do this in SQL without user variables is to write a *derived table* subquery. Then you can use column aliases to refer to the results of those complex expressions:

```
SELECT tax1, owe, IF(owe=0, 0,tax1/owe) AS ratio
FROM (
  SELECT
    (complicated calculation formula) AS tax1,
    (another complicated calculation formula) AS owe
  FROM ...
) AS _sub
```

MySQL has some problems optimizing subqueries, but the case of a derived table isn't one of the bad cases.

The warning about MySQL and subqueries is about using subqueries in range conditions in the WHERE clause. MySQL can't figure out that the subquery is constant, and it'll re-evaluate the subquery repeatedly as a *dependent subquery* even when that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use variables in select statements for sequential evaluation, aggregation, group statistics and classification of data.

**This is an example of :**

*MySQL Make a list of top X records per category, combining every record with its previous difference*

```
create table if not exists 
        closemovers engine=memory 
select 
          code 
        , date 
        , close 
        , rank 
        , prevclose 
        , sign 
        , cumm 
from 
        ( select 
                  `code` 
                , `date` 
                , `close` 
                , @rank := if( @code = code , @rank + 1 , 1) as rank 
                , @prevclose := if( @code = code , cast( @prclose as decimal(10,3) ), null) as prevclose 
                , if(@code = code, sign( @prclose - close), NULL) as sign 
                , @cumm := if(@code = code and @psign = sign(@prclose - close), @cumm + 1 , 1) as cumm
                , @psign := sign(@prclose - close) 
                , @code := code
                , @prclose := close 
        from 
            companyhistory 
        order by 
            code, date 
         ) as ranked 
 join 
        pricefeed 
                using (code) 
where 
        rank < 10 
        and sign is not null ;
```

I hope this can give you a hint